# Three.js translate mesh geometries of a loaded glb model to have same center with it's bounding box

Tags: three.js

Three.js: a loaded glb model has center different with it's bounding box center. How can I translate all it's mesh geometries to have same center with its bounding box?

For clearance: when I set position of bounding box = position of model. The bounding box will not cover the model anymore (picture below).

Because I will use bounding box for creating canon rigid body, so that position of model will be updated by rigid body. So I need to translate mesh position in model to have center = bounding box center.

In the picture: 3 models, 3 bounding boxes and 3 boxHelper(red).

[image: bounding box illustration]

Comment: Can you please share the `glb` model in this thread?

Comment: @Mugen87 I uploaded a runable project for reference here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kPvxMgAmmrST2XJvDHvO6DUnjLPVqTf1 . You can find the model name model.glb inside models folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bounding box is computed correctly. The problem is that your `blockBounding` mesh is not positioned at the right place.

You have to position `blockBounding` at the center point of the bounding box (not at the model's position). Besides, it is also not necessary to apply a rotation to `blockBounding`. An instance of `Box3` is an axis-aligned bounding box (AABB). So it's totally sufficient to do this:

```
blockBounding.position.copy( center ); // "center" is the center point of the model's AABB
```

The result looks like so:

[image]

`three.js R107`